# How can I design an JPA entity setter that depends on business code?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

}
```

To set the password, one must provide the plain-text password, but the actual password stored is a hash of the plain-text password. The problem is that the actual hash calculation is business dependent. More specifically, I have the following interface and Session Bean:

```
public interface PasswordHash {
    String hash(String password);
}

@Stateless
public class UserManager {

    @Inject
    private PasswordHash phash;

    public void changeUserPassword(User user, String newPassword) {
        String passwordHash = phash.hash(newPassword);
        /*Set password of 'user'*/
    }
}
```

Is there a way to design a setter for 'password' field of the User entity so that UserManager can change its value, but no one else can do that? If its not possible, Is there another way I can securely set the password, without exposing the PasswordHash interface to the client? Note that CDI is not available to the Entity class, so I cannot inject an instance of PasswordHash directly into it.

Comment: @BalusC but i need to define `password` somewhere, and has to be on the same table as `username` because I'm using container-managed security with form login. Besides that, there are other cases where similar situation happens, and it would be better if I could solve this without changing the actual persistent data definition.

Comment: I don't really see what the issue is. Can't you use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` function and maybe have a `@Transient PasswordHash hasher` property on the entity?

Comment: @coladict the issue is that this behavior must not be exposed from the `User` entity because its a business matter. The actual `PasswordHash` implementation is available via CDI only to the `UserManager` class because that's the class responsible for the business logic. I can use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` if I make `UserManager` be an entity listener, but I would have to check if password was actually changed and I'm trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of dealing with this is not to expose the User entity directly from your service layer, only use it internally for persistence. What you usually end up doing is essentially duplicating some entities, and copying stuff back and forth. These "copied" classes are sometimes called Data Transfer Objects. There are tools like [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) to make this easier, although arguably not prettier.

A second way is to fight Enterprise Java, and to *avoid* these [Anemic Objects](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Sooner or later though, you might have to do programmatic lookup because, as you say, the entities are not CDI-enabled. This is not pretty either, but at least you get something that is more Object-Oriented.

Comment: I'm inclined on having a method `setPassword(UserManager manager, String plainTextPassword)` on the `User` entity that simply calls `UserManager.changeUserPassword()`, so that the client at will not be able to change password directly without involving UserManager. This is not exactly a setter, but can do what I want. What do you think of that?

Comment: Well, if you have the UserManager anyway, I would only offer set/getPasswordHash in the User object itself. Than means, if another object wants to change the password, it has to get the UserMaanger and generate the hash before it sets it. Also, you could create a Hash class to avoid setting a non-hashed string accidentally into the User.

Comment: I liked the idea. I can make the `Hash` class be internal to `UserManager` with no public constructor, and have a method, say `UserManager.createHash(String password)`, which is the only way to obtain an instance to `Hash`.